# Can firebase dynamic links be used for generic app invites and page-specific invites to track referrals?

Tags: firebase-dynamic-links

I am creating an app that has a feature similar to clubhouse rooms (same room concept, but not audio specific). Can I use firebase dynamic linking to have invite codes that are general for the whole app as well as invite codes that specific to a user in a room?

ie.
general case: User1 invites User2 to the app and they both get a referral bonus and User2 goes through the standard onboarding.

specific case:  Can I also have room-specific invites, where User3 creates Room_ABC and invites User4 to Room_ABC; both User3 and User 4 get a referral bonus, but User4's onboarding is unique and is directed to Room_ABC during onboarding.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. The dynamic Links can have parameters

I would use for both cases URL Parameters:

1 Case a general share from a user where the parameter is the `uid` of the user who shared.

2 Case share to a specific group where you would have the `uid` of the user who shared and the `uid` of the group.

I use a similar concept in one of my Apps. Here the code I use to generate those links:

```dart
import 'package:firebase_dynamic_links/firebase_dynamic_links.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sendifo/models/group.dart';
import 'localization.dart';

class DynamicLinksService {
  static Future<Uri> getGroupDynamicLink(
      BuildContext context, Group group) async {
    final DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
      uriPrefix: 'https://sendifo.page.link',
      link: Uri.parse(
          'https://sendifo.page.link/add_group/?groupID=${group.uid}'),
      dynamicLinkParametersOptions: DynamicLinkParametersOptions(
          shortDynamicLinkPathLength: ShortDynamicLinkPathLength.unguessable),
      androidParameters: AndroidParameters(
        packageName: 'com.sendifo',
        minimumVersion: 0,
      ),
      iosParameters: IosParameters(
        bundleId: 'com.sendifo',
        minimumVersion: '0',
        appStoreId: '1559453273',
      ),
      socialMetaTagParameters: SocialMetaTagParameters(
          title: AppLocalization.of(context).getMessage('join_info_group'),
          description: group.title,
          imageUrl: Uri.parse(group.image)),
    );

    final link = await parameters.buildUrl();
    final ShortDynamicLink shortenedLink =
        await DynamicLinkParameters.shortenUrl(
      link,
      DynamicLinkParametersOptions(
          shortDynamicLinkPathLength: ShortDynamicLinkPathLength.unguessable),
    );

    final Uri dynamicUrl = shortenedLink.shortUrl;

    return dynamicUrl;
  }
}
```